# Can't use ranges-v3 with boost graph library

Tags: c++, boost, range, boost-graph

If I try to use the BGL and ranges-v3 I have to take special care in including the ranges-v3 includes after the BGL ones. Otherwise I get a lot of compilation errors like the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/range/v3/view/adaptor.hpp:18,
                 from /home/jjcasmar/projects/VNCS/src/VNCS/Generators/../../VNCS/Spaces.h:13,
                 from /home/jjcasmar/projects/VNCS/src/VNCS/Generators/Gen212/Gen212.h:7,
                 from /home/jjcasmar/projects/VNCS/src/VNCS/Generators/Gen212/Gen212.cpp:1:
/usr/include/range/v3/algorithm/result_types.hpp:96:13: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   96 |             RANGES_ALGO_RESULT_AUX_2(in_out_result, I, in, O, out)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/range/v3/algorithm/result_types.hpp:96:13: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/include/range/v3/algorithm/result_types.hpp:96:13: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/include/range/v3/algorithm/result_types.hpp:96:13: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

To workaround this I am just changing the order of my includes, so ranges-v3 comes before the BGL ones. However this feels like a poor workaround and can't be applied always.

Is there any way to fix this properly?

Comment: Can you include a minimal reproducing example, and potentially the versions concerned

Comment: Actually, i find what was the issue. I had a `using namespace boost` in the headers where I declared my graphs types. I removed that and eveything is fixed

Comment: That's precisely what I expected to find - which is the value of asking for minimal examples